# Rails 4 - Restful index action for for both get and post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I made 'search' action available for both get and post

```
resources :wba_partners do
    collection do
      match "wba_partners/search" => "wba_partner#search", via: [:get, :post]
    end
  end
```

for POST method it works as it should be '/wba_partners/search'.
for Get method it is throwing error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WbaPartnersController#show
Couldn't find WbaPartner with 'id'=search
```

Any idea how it can be solved? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post `rake routes` output to the question?

Comment: provide please request data, and controllers code processing the request.